# accounting coding "(unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'datetime.datetime')"

Tags: python

I'm a python student writing codes from GitHub
here's the problem

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
today = datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1)


def due_by(row):
due_days = max(0, (row['due_date'] - today).days)
week_due = int(due_days / 7)
return '< {} weeks'.format(week_due + 1)

ar['due_by'] = ar.apply(due_by, axis=1)

outstanding = ar[ar['amount_due'] > 0]

outstanding
```

typeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'datetime.datetime'

I'm practicing accounting oriented coding from https://github.com/firmai/techniques/blob/master/Accounting%20Analyses/Aged%20Debtors.ipynb Hence the code it's not mine just for education and practice, I'm an accounting student transitioning toward data analyst/business analyst role

Answer (score 0):

This is happening probably because the `due_date` column is not a datatime object and is just a string. So, to reformat it to datetime object use:

```py
ar["due_date"] = pd.to_datetime(ar["due_date"])
# the rest of the code, including the function
```